# How can I give a bash script the ability to login?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to run a face recognition program at wake-up in order to remove the need to write the password each time on my Mac. 
For now, I've used a combination of sleepwatcher, imagesnap and openCV and I have gotten the program to take and process an image each time I wake my computer from sleep.
The only thing I don't know how to do is to give this script the ability to login once my face is recognised.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Cool idea. I think there is still a long way to go. No idea how it works on macos, on linux we have [PAM](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam).

Comment: There definitely is a long way to go but having a way to login would be a great start